# How to auto restart go web server if it is stopped

Tags: go

I tried to apply a mechanism that allow the go web server to be automatically restarted when it's stopped.

The way I do it, by putting the `server.ListenAndServe()` inside an infinite loop. Since the `.ListenAndServe()` is blocking, I felt it's ok to do that. Here are the full code:

```
func main() {
    // ...

    isStarted := false
    for true {
        if isStarted {
            fmt.Println("===================================== RESTARTING WEB SERVER")
        }

        log.Println(server.ListenAndServe())
        isStarted = true

        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

When I run the app, what happen is quite different than what I expected. The web server won't start.

Am I doing it wrong? or is there any better and correct way? Thank you in advance

```
===================================== RESTARTING WEB SERVER
2019/03/13 10:01:03 http: Server closed
===================================== RESTARTING WEB SERVER
2019/03/13 10:01:04 http: Server closed
===================================== RESTARTING WEB SERVER
2019/03/13 10:01:05 http: Server closed
===================================== RESTARTING WEB SERVER
2019/03/13 10:01:06 http: Server closed
===================================== RESTARTING WEB SERVER
2019/03/13 10:01:07 http: Server closed
===================================== RESTARTING WEB SERVER
2019/03/13 10:01:08 http: Server closed
===================================== RESTARTING WEB SERVER
2019/03/13 10:01:09 http: Server closed
===================================== RESTARTING WEB SERVER
2019/03/13 10:01:10 http: Server closed
===================================== RESTARTING WEB SERVER
2019/03/13 10:01:11 http: Server closed
===================================== RESTARTING WEB SERVER
2019/03/13 10:01:12 http: Server closed
===================================== RESTARTING WEB SERVER
2019/03/13 10:01:13 http: Server closed
===================================== RESTARTING WEB SERVER
2019/03/13 10:01:14 http: Server closed
```

Comment: You want the Task Runner(https://github.com/oxequa/realize).

Comment: On which operating system?

Comment: Maybe you should dig about graceful restart servers and libs such as https://github.com/facebookgo/grace .

Comment: it is unclear if you are looking for a server side process manager (systemd/supervidor etc), a development desk tool (realize/gaper) or to write your own watcher system. Post the whole code at least, and the command to start you process.

Comment: Seems like some other piece of code is stopping the server.

Answer (score 2):

You need a process control system. That allows you to run and control a number of processes.

Ex: Systemd, Supervisord

Supervisord is a good option.

Read the documentation on http://supervisord.org/